# How to add an arrow in a chart pointing some data

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am currently working on a module to create charts to display data.
I use **System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart**.

I have two striplines showing the the average result we got and another one showing what we want.

So far I was really happy with what I had but I want to add explicit arrow to point these lines. And I can't figure out how to do it.

I saw that Line Annotation might be of help but I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted.

Here is an example of what I would like to do :

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the arrow head added to the two colored lines or do you want to add the two black arrow lines with text?

Comment: Two black arrow lines with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a choice of using

- Annotations or
- GDI+ drawing

In both cases the challenge is to get the **positions** right.

The more natural way to go is using `Annotations`, so let's look at this first:

There are various types but different capabilities; text can be displayed by `RectangleAnnotation` or a `TextAnnotation`. Lines and arrowheads can only be displayed by `LineAnnotations`. So we need a pair of `Line`- plus `TextAnnotation` for each of your two lines.

Like many other chart elements annotations are positioned in **percentages** of their respective **containers**; this makes things rather tricky at times.

To place a line annotation all to the right of the chart you could set its `X` property to `100`; to let it go to the left you set the width to a negative number. The problems are starting after that..

To find out where the right edge of the `ChartArea` is you need to code the `Pre- or PostPaint` event and use the `ToRectangleF` method.

To find out the y-value you will want to calculate it from a **data value**; for this you can use the `AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition` method, which converts to pixels, from which you can calculate the percantage using the chart's `ClientArea` along with the `ChartArea` percentage size.

Complicated? Yup. `Annotations` get a lot simpler to use if you can **anchor** them to a certain `DataPoint`; but yours are outside the `ChartArea`..

Here is a function that should help when doing the calculations:

```
double PercentFromValue(Chart chart, ChartArea ca, double value)
{
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    RectangleF car = ca.Position.ToRectangleF();
    double py = ay.ValueToPixelPosition(value);
    int caHeight = (int)(chart.ClientRectangle.Height * car.Height / 100f);
    return 100d * py / caHeight;
}
```

Note that it will only work reliably when called from of of the `Pre/PostPaint` events..

So this is an example of a `PrePaint` event that positions a `LineAnnotation lAnn`:

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle cr = chart1.ClientRectangle;
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    RectangleF car = ca.Position.ToRectangleF();

    lAnn.Width = car.Width - lAnn.X;
    lAnn.Y =  PercentFromValue(chart1, ca, someDataValue);
}
```

When you insert a valid DataPoint YValue the starting y-position will be set. You can play with it until you find a nice combination of setting the four position properties..

When creating and adding the four(!) annotations you may want to keep class level references, so you won't have to refer to them from the Annotations collection..

For the `LineAnnotation` you will want to set the linewidth, color and the capstyle, either using the  `EndCap`  or the `StartCap`:

`lAnn.EndCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.Arrow;`

---

GDI+ drawing is more straight-forward, provided you know where you want to draw the lines and the text.

It is also done in the PrePaint event, again using the ValueToPixelPosition to find the pixelposition of the two data lines.. Other than that is  all the usual stuff with `Graphics.DrawLine`, a `Pen` with and `Start- or EndCap` and `Graphics.DrawString` or maybe `TextRenderer.DrawText`..

I'm frankly not sure which way I would choose..

Answer (score 0):

create triangle image and set the marker image as:

```
Chart1.Series.Points.AddXY(0, 10);
Chart1.Series.Points.AddXY(20,10);
Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].MarkerImage = "TriangleImage.bmp";
Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].MarkerImageTransparentColor = Color.White;

or
Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;
```